# Passing a Java string to Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, string

I am trying to load a table with data by initializing a Javascript variable with a string in JSON format. If I declare:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var data = new String("{totalCount: '1', identifier: 'EntityID', items: [{'EntityID':'1','Country':'United States','Region':'','State':'California','County':'Santa Clara','City':'San Jose','ZipCode':'95134'}]}");
var d3 = eval('(' + data + ')');
<span dojoType="dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore" jsId="dataStore" data=d3></span>
</script>
```

then my table will correctly load the row.

I have tried initializing a Java string before my script and then passing that object into a Javascript variable like so:

```
<%
String d = "{totalCount: '1', identifier: 'EntityID', items: [{'EntityID':'1','Country':'United States','Region':'','State':'California','County':'Santa Clara','City':'San Jose','ZipCode':'95134'}]}";
%>

<script type="text/javascript">
var data = new String(<%=d%>);
// var data = new String(d) // tried this as well
var d3 = eval('(' + data + ')');
<span dojoType="dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore" jsId="dataStore" data=d3></span>
</script>
```

My table does not recognize this and is unable to load the row when I attempt to pass it this way. How can I properly pass a Java string to Javascript so that my table will be able to load the data?

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I should have posted the console log. The error is: `error in getting data for table: table. Error dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore: No JSON source data was provided as either URL or a nested Javascript object.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with quotes around.

```
var data = new String("<%= d %>");
```

Comment: @raphnguyen Yep, "finicky".. that's how they've always been.