# How to pass Json Code in Java to Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, json, extjs

Im trying to pass a Collection of items converted into String with JsonArray to my Javascript but dont work.

This is the code of the class

```
    InformeAmenazasAGR = manager.preparaInformeRiesgoActivos(idDimension, tipoActivo, idActivo, tipoActivoTexto, nombreActivo, recursos);       

    JSONArray JSonArray = new JSONArray();      
    JSonArray.put(InformeAmenazasAGR);
    String texto = JSonArray.toString();
    //Delete the first and last char.
    texto = texto.substring(1, texto.length()-1);   

    request.setAttribute("InformeAmenazasAGR", texto);
    return mapping.findForward( "informeActivosAGR" );
```

This returns one String like this:

```
[
["16","E.1","Errores de los usuarios","7","1128750","1015875"],
["20","E.5","Deficiencias en la organización","7","752500","526750"],
]
```

My JSP with Javascript (im using ExtJS and follow I tried [Passing a Java string to Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17954124/passing-a-java-string-to-javascript) post but dont work)

```
var DatosAmenazas = new String("<%request.getAttribute("InformeAmenazasAGR");%>");
var amenazaStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'Amenazas',
    data: DatosAmenazas     
});
```

What am i doing wrong?
Thank you in advance

EDIT: If i put the raw String that i save in `request.setAttribute("InformeAmenazasAGR", texto);` it works:

```
var amenazaStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'Amenazas',
    data: [
           ["16","E.1","Errores de los usuarios","7","1128750","1015875"],
           ["20","E.5","Deficiencias en la organización","7","752500","526750"],
          ]
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using the Java scriptlet inside javascript is not good practice,

instead you can use the $(InformeAmenazasAGR) to set the request attribute value to a hidden element and  **put the hidden element anywhere inside your html `<body>`** like this,

```
<input type="hidden" id="jsonData" value="${InformeAmenazasAGR}">
```

then, get the hidden element value like,

```
var DatosAmenazas = new String($('#jsonData').val());
```

if you need the request attribute `InformeAmenazasAGR` to be converted into json data then instead of above you can change your above line as,

```
var DatosAmenazas = JSON.parse($('#jsonData').val());
```

**FYI:** Java  scriptlets run on server side while javascript on client side

Comment: I dont understand at all (sorry, im new with js). i added the line `<input type="hidden" id="jsonData" value="${InformeAmenazasAGR}">` before the `<script>` and the var `DatosAmenazas = new String($('#jsonData').val());` before the `amenazaStore` but now the page is white without load anything. i added a little description more in the question. Thank you.

Comment: @S. Moreno do not put the hidden element before the '<script>' tag but instead put it anywhere in your html '<body>' tag. Also try printing the value of variable 'DatosAmenazas' using 'alert(DatosAmenazas);' after you initialize it. See the updated answer.